# Domain Controller computer name does not use FQDN

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory, fqdn

I've been experiencing some network issues on a domain controller.  Ended up having to [reinstall the TCP/IP stack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325356) which ended up fixing most of the issues.  However, I'm having replication and GPO issues since the server is not registering in DNS with its FQDN.  It seems like this is because its "Full computer name" does not contain the domain name as it should.

It looks like this:

[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit:**
A few more notes.  In DNS, the A record is correct.  However, there is a NS record for "SERVERNAME." .  The CNAME entry for the server in _msdcs is also "SERVERNAME." (and keeps getting replicated as such.. even after changing it) .  In ADUC, the computer object for the server shows the DNS name as "SERVERNAME" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the "Change..." button on the Computer name tab.  It will give you a warning and in the next window click "More..."  Type in dom.domain.com for the "Primary DNS suffix of this computer" field and it should display correctly in the "Full Server Name" field now.  May have to reboot, I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks from me too. We've got a bunch of Win 7 and Win Server 2008 R2 and they exhibit this randomly. Some of then pickup the domain name without having to add the primary dns suffix while for the ones that don't I have to follow this method. Any ideas WHY this happens on some workstations only? All workstations are mirrors in terms of OS Config and Software.

Answer (score 0):

Go into DNS, navigate to the domain, look for the record for servername.  Take the . off the end of the server name.

Comment: The A record is correct for the server